# Implementation of sequential LU decomposition in C++

Tags: c++, matrix

I am trying to follow the Guassian Elimination algorithm in https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs554/fa2015/notes/06_lu_8up.pdf in order to implement LU factorization and eventually parallelize it with openmp. Does the following algorithm look correct, where `l` is the multiplier and m is the matrix?

```
void decompose2(double **m) {
    begin =clock();
    int i=0, j=0, k=0;

    for(k = 1; k < size - 1; k++)
    {
      for(i = k + 1; i < size; i++)
      {
        l[i][k] = m[i][k]/m[k][k];
      }

      for(j = k + 1; j < size; j++)
      {
        for(i = k + 1; k < size; k++)
        {
          m[i][j] = m[i][j] - (l[i][k]*m[k][j]);
        }
      }

    }
    end = clock();
}
```

I don't think it is correct because according to a different paper the times I am getting after parallelization on the same number of processors are completely different.

Answer (score 0):

"Does the following algorithm look correct, …" -- No, because

- arrays are 0-index in C++,
- `double[size][size]` (which you are likely using) is not convertible to `double**`,
- `int` is not a good type for iterators (use `size_t` instead),
- you don't check if `m[k][k]` might be (close to) zero, when you might have to swap rows.

Please notice that I only looked at the obvious implementation errors, not at possible instances to make the code better, e.g. increasing the stability of the calculation.